# Upload apple watch to app store ( iPhone app already uploaded)

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I have an ios app which is already live in app store, but now i added watch kit for notifications as target in my existing project. 
So how to upload watchKit in apps tore. Does i. need to create a new app in itunes store or the existing one will work?

I tested apple watch notification in a realtime watch device. It's working fine. I need help about uploading in itunes store.

Comment: You need to embed the watch extensionin a new version of your existing app and release that as an update to the current app

Comment: You mean to say there is no need for an extra app in itune store?

Comment: I have to build an archive as i do before and push the build in itunes store. Is this you are saying?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The watch app is part of your main app. Once the new version of your app is installed the user can install your watch app from the "Watch" app on your phone.

Comment: ERROR ITMS-90054: "This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the previous version. If you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to create a new application in App Store Connect."
An unknown error occurred.

I'm getting this error while uploading app in itune store. @Paulw11 What is this issue?

Comment: As the message says, you have changed the bundle Id of your app. You can't do this.  Your main app must have the same bundle id as the previous version. The watch extension must have a different but related bundle id

Comment: I didn't change it. Its same

Comment: That's not what the error is telling you.

Comment: I received this email from itune store. Then i enabled bit code in project level. archived and while uplading getting this error.

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "d.moat". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

Invalid Executable - The executable '***.app/Watch/***WatchKit.app/PlugIns/***WatchKit Extension.appex/***WatchKit Extension' does not contain bitcode.

Comment: You must either have bitcode enabled for every component in your bundle or none.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174169/discussion-between-mubashar-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the watch app is part of main app. No need to create an individual app in itunes store. 
Just create the profiles for iWatch and add in xcode. Now build and Archive. Push to itunes store.